# What is the difference between junit vs psvm

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, tdd

What is the difference between junit and psvm (public static void main, so if we are gonna test without test frameworks). We can use psvm for all test purposes, JUnit seems more comfortable, but this answer is wrong i think

Comment: As JUnit is written in Java, of course you can rewrite the features of JUnit yourself in Java. But don't: JUnit is a featureful and thoroughly-tested library. People have already solved that problem: leverage their work to do something more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply spoken: no, you **can't** use psvm for all test purposes. With Junit, I go into my test classes, and by adding/removing the @Test annotation, I influence what will happen when I click on "run as unit test" within eclipse. I also can select a whole package in eclipse and "run as unit test" - you cant do that for the multiple mains in there.

Besides: my test code sits in the **test** project; your psvm test code lives in your **production** class!

And beyond that: with JUnit, I get automated full scale information about passes/fails ...

I could probably go on and on; the main thing here is: if you think that you can do the same things with "psvm" that JUnit allows for then my guess is: you haven't been using JUnit in real life for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: thank you, p.s. but actually i'm using it for more than 5 min :) for skipping test better add @Ignore annotation

Comment: Touche. I have to admit that I dont get the purpose of your question then; but I guess the key point is: sure, you can "copy" most of the things that JUnit does; but you need to put in a lot of work to re-invent a wheel that is already there.

Comment: I was asked this in interview and got a little stuck, now I've got some keys from you response (about code place and running). thank you! :)